# View is not updated when data changes, React,js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to react, I am programming the function `onAdd()`, when I call that it should add the item to `state` and then I update the hook with the new item `setBooks(state)`.

```
const state = {
  books: [
    { id: 0, rating: 4, title: "Harry Potter y el cáliz de fuego", image: "libro01.jpg"},
    { id: 1, rating: 3, title: "The shining", image: "libro02.jpg" },
    { id: 2, rating: 5, title: "Código Da Vinci", image: "libro03.jpg" },
    { id: 3, rating: 5, title: "El principito", image: "libro04.jpg" },
    { id: 4, rating: 5, title: "Sobrenatural", image: "libro05.jpg" },
  ],
  copyBooks: []
};

function App() {

  const [books, setBooks] = useState(state);

  const onAdd = (item)=>{
    //add new item to books
    console.log('Add: ', item);
    const id = state.books[state.books.length-1].id++;
    item['id'] = id;
    state.books.push(item);
    setBooks(state);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu onadd={onAdd}/>
      <List items={books.books}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this works fine internally, I print the books object and it is up to date.
When I try to print the data of the child `<List />` component is not printed, until I make a change on the server and it is updated.
I came to the conclusion that the problem is that the List component `<List />` is not refreshed.

`books` **refers to hooks** and `books.books` to the **data**.

I do not know how I can solve it, I know it is something basic but I am starting in this technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onAdd` function is mutating state, meaning React sees the same object reference as before and will not update. To make sure an update happens, copy the array and set the state to the new copy:

```js
const onAdd = (item) => {
  //add new item to books
  console.log('Add: ', item);
  const id = state.books[state.books.length-1].id + 1;
  item['id'] = id;
  const newBooks = [...state.books, item];
  setBooks({ ...state, books: newBooks });
}
```

Edit: by the way, I might recommend some less confusing terminology when naming variables. The local `books` variable actually refers to the entire *state* and then `books.books` refers to the actual books... that's going to cause mistakes because it's very confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much, it already works. You're right, I have to rename those confusing variables.